# Custom dashboard reports for different users

Tags: admin

I’m working on a magento install, and would like some users NOT to be able to see total sales to date. (lifetime sales)

Is that possible / configurable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure this issue.

1. Create new role admin->system->permissions->roles and click [Add new role].
2. On Role Resources tab check only specific resources like: [image: Role Resources]
3. Save role
4. Create new admin user admin->system->permissions->users and click [Add new user].
5. Attach the role created above to this user and save.